# optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two different method in my java application and each method performing some task on same table `upload_table`. Please find the task performed by the two different methods below.

```
@Override
@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)
public void createClaimsFromNewUploadAndMarkUploadAsPending(Long uploadId) {
  try {
 ExcelClaimUpload claimUpload = excelClaimUploadRepository.findOne(uploadId);  // it will fetch records from upload_table
  if (claimUpload == null || !claimUpload.isNewUpload()) return;
  createPendingProcessingClaimsFrom(claimUpload);
  claimUpload.setStatus(PENDING);
  }catch(Exception e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

The above task will fetch details from the same table `upload_table`.

```
@Override
@Transactional
public ExcelClaimUpload createNewClaimUpload(ExcelClaimUpload claimUpload) {
 claimUpload.setStatus(NEW);
 List<UploadLineItem> uploadLineItems = claimUpload.getUploadLineItems();
 if(claimUpload.getUploadLineItems() != null && claimUpload.getUploadLineItems().size()==0) {
  claimUpLoad.setRowErrors(true);
 }
uploadLineItemService.save(uploadLineItems); // it will save the records in upload_table
claimUpLoad = excelClaimUploadRepository.save(claimUpload);
 }
return claimUpLoad;
}
```

The above task will save records to the same table `upload_table`.

But the above methods will be triggered by two different thread ( process ).

At some point of time am getting the below exception while these task executing via corn job.

```
optimistic locking failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.StaleObjectStateException: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)
```

How can i avoid this exception ?

I have tried with the `@Transactional(isolation = Isolation.SERIALIZABLE)` where it will fetch the records from the table `upload_table` but no luck.

Comment: This error happens when you try to update a row in your table `upload_table` that has been already updated or deleted

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20324691/spring-hibernate-optimistic-locking-issue